# Python help for instance does not show __init__ at the beginning

Tags: python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop, python-3.8

I just created a simple python class to learn more about magic methods and I used REPL to instantiate an object. But when I type `help(<instance>)` it does not show the `__init__()` method at the beginning. How do I get the init method to be showed at the beginning of the help. This is important because the person should see the init method to know how to instantiate it.

```
class vector:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __rmul__(self,const):
        if type(const) == int:
            return vector(self.x*const,self.y*const)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"an int type is expected but {type(const)} is provided")

    def __mul__(self,const):
        return vector(self.x*const,self.y*const)

    def __add__(self,other):
        if type(self) == type(other):
            return vector(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"type of other should be {type(other)}")

    def __radd__(self,other):
        if type(self) == type(other):
            return vector(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"type of other should be {type(other)}")

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if type(self) == type(other) and self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __len__(self):
        return (self.x**2 + self.y**2)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"vector({self.x},{self.y})"
```

[image: here is screenshot of the REPL help output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `help` function is a wrapper of `pydoc.help`, which uses [`pydoc.sort_attributes`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pydoc.py#L880) to sort the names of attributes of a class, so you can patch it with a wrapper function that re-sorts the attributes based on whether its name is equal to `__init__`:

```
import pydoc

def sort_attributes_wrapper(attrs, object):
    orig_sort_attributes(attrs, object)
    attrs.sort(key=lambda t: t[0] != '__init__')

orig_sort_attributes = pydoc.sort_attributes
pydoc.sort_attributes = sort_attributes_wrapper
```

so that `help(vector)` outputs:

```
Help on class vector in module __main__:

class vector(builtins.object)
 |  vector(x, y)
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, x, y)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  __add__(self, other)
 |  
 |  __eq__(self, other)
 |      Return self==value.
...
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ThinScratchyParallelalgorithm